# Who drew the ten Princes in "Damnation City"?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, publishing, vampire-the-requiem, art

In *Damnation City* there is a section with ten princes with artwork that is really cool. Does anyone know the identity of the artist?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As one of the artists involved with the book, I know that Mike Huddleston did those.
-CSG

Comment: Welcome @Craig! I was going to ask you to cite your source, but then I noticed your name in the [list of artists](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4811/who-drew-the-ten-princes-in-damnation-city/4820#4820) in the other answer. Thanks for your first hand info!

Comment: I also did the layout and was the AD that hired him ;)

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure who did that exact piece but the artists listed are: Tomasz Jedruszek, Sam Araya, Tom Biondolillo, Avery Butterworth, Craig S Grant, Will & Sara Hindmarch, Mike Huddleston, Becky Jollensten, Mathias Kollros, Patrick McEvoy, Justin Norman, Nick Stakal, Arend Stahrmann, Andy Trabbold, and Chad Michael Ward